# How to capture packets that are within net-bridge netmask?

Tags: linux, networking, pcap, netfilter

I created a net-bridge that is 10.10.0.1/16 (via "brctl addbr"),

and a docker container bridged on it has an IP like 10.10.0.15,

It seems that no matter whatever tools I use (like Netfilter and Pcap), when I ping 10.10.0.16 (which doesn't actually exist) inside container, this outgoing packet cannot be captured by me, while ping 10.11.0.16 (which doesn't actually exist as well, but without net-bridge netmask) can be captured !

I don't know how to capture the former one, because I want to capture it and redirect it to another address, so how can I achieve this?

```
docker@ABCDEF01# ifconfig
  eth0 -- 10.10.0.15/16

docker@ABCDEF01# ping 10.10.0.16  (Pcap not response, how to capture this one?)

docker@ABCDEF01# ping 10.11.0.16  (Pcap has response)
```

Comment: You'd normally have a bridge device in addition to eth0 etc. So you would capture on that interface, and not on eth0.